# Google Sheets Delete Cell with specific background color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get this function to work in Apps Script but for the life of me I cant seem to find the problem.

I have a range of cells highlighted in one column in my sheet.  I want to delete all the contents from those cells - not the rows.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function clearGreen() {

  var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  for (var i=0; i<bgColors.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<bgColors[i].length; j++) {
      if (bgColors[i][j] === '#D9E9D3') {
        range.getCell(i+1,j+1).clearContent();
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

The error it is returning when trying to debug is as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheets' of null
clearGreen  @ Code.gs:4
```

UPDATE:  The below solution worked perfectly and much faster than my code.  NOTE your worksheet needs to be the FIRST worksheet in your workbook, mine was sheet 59 so once I  moved it to the first position it executed perfectly.

THANK YOU!

Comment: The code worked for me. :) Where you try to run it? Via spreadsheet or the editor?

Comment: From the editor.  Im  not sure where to put it in the spreadhseet?

Comment: don't put it into a spreadsheet call it from a menu

Comment: OK I accidentally created a new Apps Script project that was not connected to the Sheet.  The code is in the right place now I think, but instead of getting an error it says it has completed but there is no change in my sheet.

Comment: How your sheet looks like?

Comment: Could you add `Logger.log(bgColors)` to end of the script? What does it log?

Comment: All cells that need to be deleted/cleared have their background color set to #d9ead3 - they are all in column A - but there is about 20,000 rows to process

Comment: 20,000 is quite much. It makes sense to use `getValues()` and `setValues()` if there are hundreds colored cells that need to clean.

Comment: @MuhammetYunus  I am getting this output which is the blue background of the header row only:

`[[#cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3, #cfe2f3]]`

Comment: @YuriKhristich I ran a formula to compare A1:A2 and if they match then set the background color of A1 to #cfe2f3 - so it is being coloured by conditional formatting.  I wonder if thats why its not picking it up as a background colour.

Comment: I doubt that conditional formatting is a cause of the error. But is would be better you to share the formula. It would help to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @YuriKhristich  It was a bit manual Im afraid.  I have 2 columns A and B so in Conditional Formatting I chose the range of column A and then chose Custom Condition of =A=B as the custom condition and set the background color 'light green 3' as the option, which is hex #D9E9D3

Comment: I'm sure the problem is because you use upper case `#D9E9D3` in the condition. But colors on the sheet are in a lower case `#d9e9d3`. See my answer.

Comment: And what does this one log?  `bgColors.forEach(row => Logger.log(row.includes('#D9E9D3')))`

Comment: @MuhammetYunus it returns a result of False only

Comment: OK, could you share with us a sample sheet please?

Comment: @MuhammetYunus sure no problem here is the link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QeAC2NgjKIznSoYbjEAY36XRBfzdMXc8bbk7l1SKNHw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the line:

```
if (bgColors[i][j] === '#D9E9D3') {
```

with:

```
if (bgColors[i][j].toUpperCase() === '#D9E9D3') {
```

And it will work much faster this way:

```
function clearGreen() {
  var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var data = range.getValues()      // <--- get all the data as an array
  for (var i=0; i<bgColors.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<bgColors[i].length; j++) {
      if (bgColors[i][j].toUpperCase() === '#D9E9D3') {
        data[i][j] = '';            // <--- change the array
      }
    }
  }
  range.setValues(data);            // <--- put the array back on the sheet
}
```

Comment: No change I am afraid.  But it did execute much faster!

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your data. Since the code is quite simple. It has no errors.

Comment: I setup a demo sheet here with edit settings:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QeAC2NgjKIznSoYbjEAY36XRBfzdMXc8bbk7l1SKNHw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: THANKYOU to @Muhammet Yunis and to Yuri Khristich for your help.  The code you suggested did indeed work.  The issue was being caused by the position of the worksheet in the workbook.  Even though the worksheet was selected, it needed to be the FIRST in the series of sheets for the code to execute.  So the position of the target worksheet is critical unless it is named I guess.

Comment: Nevertheless for me it gets sometimes the message '*An unknown error has occurred, please try again later*'. And it has to do with amount of the data (or with my internet connection maybe). The error disappears if there are about 1000 rows or less. I'm glad if it it works for you with no errors.