# Sheets Scripts- Clear cells based on background color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to clear (reset) the cell values on a sheet based on background color. I have found and changed the following 3 existing scripts.  They all execute correctly without any errors, but none of them clear the form.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tdWolaOsQ-3C3kiH8ErXVvG-OKeBsP7jV3QfFiyPaO0/edit#gid=831621147) is a link to a mirror copy of my spreadsheet.

```
//////////////////////////////////

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70788737/clear-cell-contents-based-on-color-in-google-sheets

function ClearYellow1() {
    var colorToDelete = '#CDCDB4';
    var gs = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sn = gs.getSheetByName('Temp');
    var data = sn.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
        for (var c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) {
            var cellBgColor = sn.getRange(r + 1, c + 1).getBackground();
            if (cellBgColor === colorToDelete) {
                sn.getRange(r+1,c+1).clear(); //for clearing values only use
                //sn.getRange(r + 1, c + 1).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS); //for deleting cells
                
                
            }
        }
    }
}
/////////////////////////////////////

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266797/change-cell-value-based-on-the-cells-background-color-in-google-sheets

function ClearYellow2() {
  const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Temp");
  const rng = sheet1.getDataRange();
  const colors = rng.getBackgrounds();
  const values = rng.getValues();
  colors.map((r,i)=>r.map((c,j)=>{
    if(c=='#CDCDB4'){
    values[i][j]="g";
    }}));
  rng.clearContent();
  rng.setValues(values);   
}
///////////////////////////////////////////

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521942/google-sheets-delete-cell-with-specific-background-color

function ClearYellow3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Temp");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var data = range.getValues()      // <--- get all the data as an array
  for (var i=0; i<bgColors.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<bgColors[i].length; j++) {
      if (bgColors[i][j].toUpperCase() === '#CDCDB4') {
        data[i][j] = '';            // <--- change the array
      }
    }
  }
  range.setValues(data);            // <--- put the array back on the sheet
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Third script is mine. There is no errors. But it's impossible to guess why it doesn't work with your sheet without your sheet in hand. Share a sample of your sheet.

Comment: I just tried the code on your sheet `ClearYellow3()` https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tdWolaOsQ-3C3kiH8ErXVvG-OKeBsP7jV3QfFiyPaO0/edit?usp=sharing and it works fine. It clears the yellow cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pick up the color from one cell to fix the problem.

A slight modification of code

```
function ClearYellow3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Temp");
  var color = sheet.getRange('C2').getBackground()
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var data = range.getValues()      
  for (var i=0; i<bgColors.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<bgColors[i].length; j++) {
      if (bgColors[i][j] == color) {
        data[i][j] = '';   
        // bgColors[i][j] = "#ffffff";//set to white         
      }
    }
  }
  range.setValues(data).setBackgrounds(bgColors);//reset values and backgrounds            
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Reset values based on background colors:

I set a few colors to light yellow 3 and used the debugger to see what the value was and used that value to do the comparison

```
function ClearYellow3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var data = range.getValues()      
  for (var i=0; i<bgColors.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<bgColors[i].length; j++) {
      if (bgColors[i][j] == "#fff2cc") {
        data[i][j] = '';   
        bgColors[i][j] = "#ffffff";//set to white         
      }
    }
  }
  range.setValues(data).setBackgrounds(bgColors);//reset values and backgrounds            
}
```

This worked first time without any problems

Comment: @Yuri Khristich.  I tried Cooper's code and it still does not work.  Here is a link to a mirror copy of my spreadsheet.  Thank you in advance guys. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tdWolaOsQ-3C3kiH8ErXVvG-OKeBsP7jV3QfFiyPaO0/edit?usp=sharing        (This should now be a sharable link)

Comment: You should pick up the color from one cell to fix the problem.

Comment: @MikeSteelson  don't understand your comment.  I have no prroblem

Comment: I tried and faced the same problem ... may be due to PC screen paramaters ?

Comment: I just copied the code and pasted it into the script editor and put light yellow 3 into a block of cells and they all turned white and got cleared.  I'm sorry but if you guys can't run scripts on your own, I can't help you.

Comment: I appreciate your help looking into this Cooper.  I am new to scripts.  I currently have this form clearing the cells using  var rangesAddressesList = ['C6:J6', 'P6:W6', ...]; resetByRangesList_(sheet, rangesAddressesList);
Inserting every cell to clear is very monotonous. But, that script seems to work. My guess is that the problem isn't in the code but in the sheet's settings.  I'll do a little more digging into this and add the solution here when I find it.

Comment: @Mike Steelson  I like the PickColor function you added.  I never thought of that, but I can see how it can solve many issues when using colors.  I tried to run the script on my Mac and I still had the same result as I did on my PC.  Thank you for your help also.

Comment: I was able to get it to work.  I read that sometimes "issues" may come up due to having more than one Google account /Profile on the browser.  I wish I could remember where I read it.  In any case, I deleted my son's school account from my chrome browser and that seemed to correct it.  Thank you for both of your help.